# How can i fix 'npx react-native run-android' error?

Tags: android, react-native, cmd, emulation, device

I use 'npx react-native run-android' command and get this error:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\aisir\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\RNTestWithNode\clientRN\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\aisir\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\RNTestWithNode\clientRN\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\aisir\OneDrive\������� ����\RNTestWithNode\clientRN\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 195

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\aisir\OneDrive\Р Р°Р±РѕС‡РёР№ СЃС‚РѕР»\RNTestWithNode\clientRN\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\aisir\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\RNTestWithNode\clientRN\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
```

Does some one know how to fix it?

Comment: It is clear from your posted error that `Рабочий стол` is being seen as `������� ����` and `Р Р°Р±РѕС‡РёР№ СЃС‚РѕР»`, so the problem is with codepage/font/encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix it. I changed the version of my project.